# Python Matplotlib scatterplot compressing the Y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science

I have some code for a school project I'm working on, and I need to create scatter plots for data on the Median household income by county and each county's investment into sustainable energy practices. For example, the first five lines of my data look like this:

```py
x = [39620, 43170, 76633, 50449, 50777]
y = [49625, 177083, 2026280, 460648, 137874]
```

The data was gathered fine, however, when I try to create a scatter plot with the data the Y-axis compressed itself to being 1,2,3,4 instead of the actual values which are in the millions.

```py
ply.scatter(x, y, norm=None)
```

The graph then appears to look like this:

[image: I]

I've looked online and can't figure this out, any help would be greatly appreciated thank you so much!

Comment: Notice the `1e8` above the graph. The scale has changed. 2 actually is 200.000.000 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [39620, 43170, 76633, 50449, 50777]
y = [49625, 177083, 2026280, 460648, 137874]

plt.figure()
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
plt.scatter(x, y, norm=None)
```